# How to prevent expanding of nativeselect contentcell vaadin

Tags: java, web, frameworks, vaadin

I am using a native select in form layout like this:
You can see that my native select content is too lengthy:

```
  accountType = new NativeSelect("Account Type:");
    accountType.setRequired(true);
    accountType.setNullSelectionItemId("--Select--");
    accountType.addItem("Regular Savings");
    accountType.addItem("Silver Savings");
    accountType.addItem("Gold Privilege");
    accountType.addItem("Advantage Premium Savings");

    idProof = new NativeSelect("ID Proof:");
    idProof.setSizeFull();
    idProof.setRequired(true);
    idProof.setNullSelectionItemId("--Select--");
    idProof.addItem("Arms License issued by State/Central Government authorities");
    idProof.addItem("Bank Pass Book with photograph issued  or its susidiaries or Nationalised Banks");


    FormLayout fLayout = new FormLayout(accountType,idProof);
```

Then I am adding this formlayout to horizontalLayout

```
 HorizontalLayout hlayout = new HorizontalLayout(fLayout,fLayout2);
```

but my idProof dropdown cell content extends the width of the parent.
How to force the dropdown to stay inside the parent layout whatever content width may it holds?

Answer (score 0):

```
idProof.setWidth(20, Unit.EM);
```

You can, of course, choose any width you want, and also, idProof.setSizeFull() is no longer necessary.